# Any workaround for this grails error on annotation exists when we upgraded grails?

Tags: grails

We have 134 of these errors and don't want to go through and fix them all.  Is there a setting in grails 5 to fix all of them in one go

`/Users/dean/workspace/tray/monorepo/groovy/tray-server/grails-app/services/tray/TaxesService.groovy: 29: Class annotated with Log annotation cannot have log field declared @ line 29, column 5. private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(TaxesService.class);`

I could not find anything to try on this subject.

Comment: Without seeing any code, the error indicates you have classes annotated with `@Log` when they have the Logger declaration as well. The annotation is essentially a short cut (among other things) for the declaration. To fix this, you either have to remove the `@Log` annotation or the declarations.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a setting in grails 5 to fix all of them in one go

There is not a setting wet support to fix all of those in one go.